# in PHP, how do I create an array of all strings between two strings?

Tags: php, parsing, string, arrays

I have a chunk of text like:

```
<b>First content</b> followed by <b>second content</b>
```

OR

```
"First content" and then "second content"
```

And I want to create an array that looks:
[1] => "First content"
[2] => "second content"

From either example, where I get the content between two tags. I've figured out how to get the first instances, but can't figure out the best way to make it recursive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what exactly is between "First content" and "second content", use `explode`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

e.g.

```
$values = explode("followed by", $yourtext);
```

(use "strip_tags" on your array-elements if you just want the plaintext)

Comment: I wound up using explode , but using my tags (<b> or " in the above example), and then logically figuring out which ones were contained in the tags. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to extract all content between specific tags, you may be best off with a HTML DOM Parser like [**simplehtmldom**](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

basically you need a regexp in form "START(.+?)END", for example

```
$a = "<b>First content</b> followed by <b>second content</b>";
preg_match_all("~<b>(.+?)</b>~", $a, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$yourArray = split(" followed by ", $yourString);

?>
```

As long as you have the same text in between each value that you want to break up into an array you can use this example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string="<b>First content</b> followed by <b>second content</b>";
$s = explode("followed by", strip_tags($string));
print_r($s);
```